# Best place to store my service sqlite db file?

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony2. I'm developping a utility service that needs to use a database for its own needs.

I want its data to be kept separated from the mysql global db used by others services/bundles.

Where is the best place to store the db file and how to specify the path ?

Sample (bad) code :

```
class MyCustomService
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->setupDB();
    }    

    private function setupDB()
    {
        $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
        $connectionParams = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
            'path' => realpath('.') . '\dbmanager.db'
        );        
       $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config); 

       //...
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
It Shouldn't be in web folder :)
```

- If your db can deleted as and when you clear cache, app/cache would be fine.
- If you want persistent database, then you can choose somewhere in app/{name of service}/db.sqlite" or data/{name of service}/db.sqlite"
- I would rather pass the name of the DB in config options

> Also note that under *NIX the user of your web server/cli must have
>   read and write permissions on the database file and read, write and
>   execute permissions on the containing directory

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up to make the db name and path as a config parameter for the bundle, wich by default point to a sqlite directory under app/